# Hardware accelerated cryptography -- fasted access from userspace?

Tags: c, linux, cryptography, kernel, embedded

So I have an embedded (Linux) system with a crypto co-processor and two userspace applications which need to use it: SSL (httpd) and proprietary code; maximizing speed and efficiency is the main requirement. I spent they day examining the kernel hooks and part registers and have come to three possible solutions:
1) Access the co-processor directly since it's memory mapped;
2) Use the /dev/crypto library
3) Use OpenSSL calls for my proprietary application

During standard operation, SSL is used very rarely and the proprietary application produces a very heavy load of plaintext needing crypto. Here's the pros and cons for each option as I see them and how I got to this quandry:

1) Direct access
--Pros: probably the fastest method, closest to complete control of the crypto co-processor, least overhead, great for the proprietary app
--Cons: Race conditions or interference could occur when SSL is being used... I'm not sure how bad two userspace apps trying to asynchronously share a hardware resource could hork things up, and I may not know until a customer finds out and complains

2) /dev/crypto
--Pros: SSL already uses it, I believe it's session-based, so sharing problems would be mitigated if not avoided completely
--Cons: More overhead, lack of documentation for proper ioctl()s to configure the co-processor correctly for optimal, high duty cycle use

3) Use SSL
--Pros: already setup and working with /dev/crypto, rarely used... so it's just there and available for crypto calls, and probably the best resource sharing management
--Cons: Probably the most overhead, may not be using /dev/crypto as efficiently as it possible, things could get bursty when both the proprietary app and httpd require SSL

I'd really like to use option 1, and will code up a test framework in the morning, but I'm curious if anyone else out there has had this problem or has any opinions. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean using *OpenSSL* calls? As far as I know there is no SSL API, just a set of protocol specifications. Personally I would go for the highest level API that fits the bill and only optimize if it doesn't match your performance expectations. `/dev/crypto` seems to require all data up front. That may be fast, but it also requires quite a large buffer if the encryption data (or AD data) is very large. You want to make sure you don't have race conditions and such. It may not just bug out, it may well compromise your security.

Comment: Yes, I did mean OpenSSL. I'm with you on the high level API. We're using /dev/crypto now and don't fully understand the plumbing. I feel like if I can't get OpenSSL going, I'm probably going to access the hardware directly (Freescale provides an API) and then figure out how to share it reliably.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as you've already indicated the pros and cons of the different options. The rest is opinion or related to the use case; there is no objective answer possible.